# How do you control the distance between two textboxes?

Tags: java, android, textview

IE: I have textbox1, and textbox2. They are both next to each other. Then I have textbox 3, and textbox4. They are aligned and under textbox1 and 2. How do you control the distance between textbox 3 and textbox 2? If I do

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

for textbox 3, it specifies the distance between textbox 3 and 1, instead of 3 and 2.

I am aiming for textbox 3 to be forced down a certain amount that textbox 2 have expanded.

[image: Shows what's happening in a way]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this problem. Here's one:

1. Place boxes 1 and 2 in a horizontal `LinearLayout`
2. Set the `layout_height` of that `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`
3. Place boxes 3 and 4 outside of that `LinearLayout` and use the same `layout_marginTop` that you've been using

Comment: Although this is a quite good method of solving the problem, but I am getting some "sibling" errors, as I am using variables outside of the relative layout. Are there any other methods you might have that can solve the "xxx is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout"?

Comment: Just change the surrounding relative layout to a vertical LinearLayout, remove any attribute that are only applicable to relative layouts, and then BVB's solution should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

this is depending on what type of layout are you actually using, and you can play with the layout parameters, see google guidelines